# Error org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have the hql query that I am executing but receive an error that I don't really understand the cause of.

This is my code:

```
@Override
public List<StaffRequest> getStaffLeaveRequest(String userID, Date startDate, Date endDate) 
{
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();        

    List<StaffRequest> results = 
    currentSession.createQuery("select new com.timesheet_Webservice.CustomEntity.StaffRequest(lr.leave_ID, lr.leave_Employee, concat(s.staff_First_Name, ' ', s.staff_Last_Name), "
            + "(lr.leave_Days*8.5), lr.leave_Comments, '1805', concat(pro.project_Pastel_Prefix, ' - ', pro.project_Description), lr.leave_Start, lr.leave_End, lr.leave_IsApproved, "
            + "(select lt.leaveType_Description from LeaveType lt where lt.leaveType_ID = lr.leave_Type)) "
            + "from Staff s, Project pro, Leave lr "
            + "where lr.leave_Employee = s.staff_Code and pro.project_Code = 1805 and lr.leave_Approved = :userID and lr.leave_IsApproved = 0 and s.staff_IsEmployee <> 0 "
            + "and lr.leave_Start between :startDate and :endDate "
            + "order by concat(s.staff_First_Name, ' ', s.staff_Last_Name)")
            .setParameter("userID",userID).setParameter("startDate", startDate).setParameter("endDate", endDate).getResultList();   

    return results;
}
```

I get this error on the webpage when trying to execute it:

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet

And also this console error:

> ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Leave leave2_ where leave2_.Leave_Employee=staff0_.Staff_Code
>   and project1_.Proj' at line 1

It seems to indicate some fault at the where clause, but I don't see anything particularly wrong.

**UPDATE:**
Entity classes

**Project**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="project")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Project_Code")
    public int project_Code;

    @Column(name="Project_Customer")
    public int project_Customer;

    //A lot more attributes...
```

}

**Staff**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="staff")
public class Staff 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="Staff_Code")
    public String staff_Code;
    ...
}
```

Comment: add Staff s, Project pro, Leave entity classes

Comment: I do have entity classes for all 3 of them

Comment: thats great. can we see them

Comment: Sorry thought you meant I should create them. Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** As you using `java.util.Date` for `Leave.leave_Start`, you should annotate with proper `@Temporal` value:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="Leave_Start")
Date leave_Start;
```

**2)** When setting your query date parameters, try using:

```
.setDate("startDate", startDate)
```

or

```
.setParameter("startDate", startDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Did as you suggested but unfortunately the error persists. With some additional testing I narrowed the cause of the error down the the "from Leave lr" by removing the other where conditions. If i run a SQL port of this query in workbench it works perfectly.

Comment: Should Leave be uppercase?

Comment: If you mean the table name then no it should be lower case but I also already fixed that and still this stubborn error persists. Might just have to resort to using native query

Comment: I tried a very simple "from Leave" query and got the same error so something must be up with my entity class

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after much testing I discovered the reason for the error. For some unknown reason the query seems to have a problem with the name of the referenced table 'leave' and produces the error whenever I try to retrieve data from it. If I however rename the table to something as simple as 'leaves' then the query executes successfully. Anyone might know why this is?

Comment: leave is a reserved word in MySQL wich is why it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently JPA follows some rule or convention of variable names and does not accept "_" and for some reason does not accept intermediate capital letters... It worked for me by changing all variables to lowercase

Comment: it is not answer by anyway, should be a comment